# Recursively call function on super

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, super

I want to recursively call a method on super, for propagating method calling up to the last superclass. This pseudocode tells what i want to do, but of course this not compiles in Java.

```
public MyClass {

    protected void method() {

        // do something on this level

        if (super instanceof MyClass) {
            MyClass superLevel = (MyClass) super;
            superLevel.method();
        }
    }
}
```

How can is achieve this behavior?

Comment: This code must be put in the super class. In the super class, you can write `if (this instance of MyClass)` but IMHO, it reveals a design flaw : the super class should not know its subclasses.

Comment: The only option is to add `super.method()` call on each level. You can only call the immediate super class method using `super`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
public class MySuperClass {
    protected void method() {
         // Whatever you want to do in super class
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MySuperClass {
    @Override
    protected void method() {
         // Whatever you want to do in this specific class

         // Call super.method
         super.method();
    }
}
```

You can use it this way in a chain of classes.

Comment: Why downvoting without explanation?

Comment: Just ignore them,There are not valid.Keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

you can not directly do that until you have can edit all those classes too. Directly only immediate parent's methods can be used not above that.

and if you can edit the parents then call `super.method()` on each level.